# Make object to be vertical center at the same time to be space between

Tags: html, css

Goal:
Make the 2 logo to be vertical center at the same time to be justify-content: space-between.

Problem:
I tried to do it but I failed.
Do you know guys how to solve it?

Other:
I have not working so much in CSS

JSbin:
https://jsbin.com/gujizoruqa/edit?html,css,output

Thank you!

```css
#page {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-areas:
    "head head"
    "nav main"
    "foot foot";
  grid-template-rows: 70px 1fr 50px;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
    position: relative;

}

#page > header {
  grid-area: head;
  background-color: #8ca0ff;
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;  

}


.test { 


}

.test2 { 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

}

#page > nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  background-color: #ffa08c;
}

#page > main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: #ffff64;
}

#page > footer {
  grid-area: foot;
  background-color: #8cffa0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section id="page">
    <header>
      <span class="test">
        <span class="test2">
          <span>
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTCPQ5XLyAjzq-NHitpSKVIsF8LorhPxewY_vERnurZLA&s" width="50" height="50" />
          </span>
          <span>
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTCPQ5XLyAjzq-NHitpSKVIsF8LorhPxewY_vERnurZLA&s" width="50" height="50" />
          </span>
        </span>
       </span>
    </header>
    <nav>Navigation</nav>
    <main>Main area</main>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is [this](https://jsbin.com/qapigiwilu/edit?html,css,output) what you want?

Comment: yes ,it is...... YOu show provde the answear in the right location

Answer (score 0):

The answer is from Vee

```
https://jsbin.com/qapigiwilu/edit?html,css,output
```

```css
#page {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-areas:
    "head head"
    "nav main"
    "foot foot";
  grid-template-rows: 70px 1fr 50px;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
    position: relative;

}

#page > header {
  grid-area: head;
  background-color: #8ca0ff;
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;  

}


.test { 
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

.test2 { 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

#page > nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  background-color: #ffa08c;
}

#page > main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: #ffff64;
}

#page > footer {
  grid-area: foot;
  background-color: #8cffa0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section id="page">
    <header>
      <span class="test">
        <span class="test2">
          <span>
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTCPQ5XLyAjzq-NHitpSKVIsF8LorhPxewY_vERnurZLA&s" width="50" height="50" />
          </span>
          <span>
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTCPQ5XLyAjzq-NHitpSKVIsF8LorhPxewY_vERnurZLA&s" width="50" height="50" />
          </span>
        </span>
       </span>
    </header>
    <nav>Navigation</nav>
    <main>Main area</main>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```